# Error installing rgdal: API to be used not found

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal

I have Fedora Workstation 34.

I have installed `gdal-devel` rpm on my system:

`sudo dnf install gdal-devel`

Now I am trying to install the R `rgdal` package.

But the installation fails with the following error message:

```
configure: API to be used as yet undetermined, searching ...
configure: error: API to be used not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/raffaele/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rgdal’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpZRbq1a/downloaded_packages’


✔ Package 'rgdal' successfully installed.
Warning message:
In utils::install.packages("rgdal", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
```

Please note that in the above the

> Package 'rgdal' successfully installed.

is wrong.

In particular it looks like it can't find an API.

How can I fix this problem and install the `rgdal` R package?

Answer (score 4):

The above instructions are for Debian/Ubuntu or similar. Dependencies in Linux need to be installed separately as indicated in the [CRAN for rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html). On Fedora use

```
sudo dnf install gdal-devel proj-devel
```

Not that `proj-devel` is necessary to prevent the error "configure: error: API to be used not found". After which in R you can use `install.packages("rgdal")`. Using the package manager is also a good solution.

Comment: Yes I confirm. Thank you very much for synthesizing it

Answer (score 1):

Based on the instructions by [dncgst](https://gist.github.com/dncgst/111b74066eaea87c92cdc5211949cd1e), I would suggest first installing the packages libgdal-dev and libproj-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin proj-bin libgdal-dev libproj-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered you can install the binaries directly from the package manager

```
sudo dnf install R-rgdal
```